# How to simplify neo4j query with multiple CASE's

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

We use the following cypher query in our project (just the relevant part, there's a bunch of MATCH and WHERE before this):

```
"RETURN entry.id AS id,\n" +
    ...
    "       CASE WHEN ljCase1 IS NOT NULL THEN {id: ljCase1.id, guide: false} \n" +
    "           ELSE CASE WHEN ljCase2 IS NOT NULL THEN {id: ljCase2.id, guide: true}\n" +
    "              ELSE CASE WHEN ljCase3 IS NOT NULL THEN {id: ljCase3.id, guide: true} END\n" +
    "         END\n" +
    "       END AS learningJourney\n" +
...
```

It works properly but I feel like this isn't done as clean as it could be.
Is there a way to simplify this part of the query?

Comment: I don't see any way to really improve upon the `CASE` expression you already have here.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something along the line of this, using COALESCE to avoid the nested CASE

```
WITH COALESCE(ljCase1,ljCase2,ljCase3) AS myCase
WITH CASE myCase 
         WHEN x THEN ..
         WHEN y THEN ..
         ELSE ..
     END
```